# get first and last element in array

Tags: php, arrays, indexing

hey there i have this array:

```
array(1) {
  ["dump"]=>
  string(38) "["24.0",24.1,24.2,24.3,24.4,24.5,24.6]"
}
```

my question:

how to get the first and the last element out from this array, so i will have:

```
$firstEle = "24.0";
```

and

```
$lastEle = "24.6";
```

anybody knows how to get those elements from the array?

i already tried this:

```
$arr = json_decode($_POST["dump"], true); 

$col0 = $arr[0];
$col1 = $arr[1];
$col2 = $arr[2];
$col3 = $arr[3];
$col4 = $arr[4];
$col5 = $arr[5];
$col6 = $arr[6];
```

i could chose $col0 and $col6, but the array could be much longer, so need a way to filter the first("24.0") and the last("24.6") element.
greetings

Comment: Have a look at [`reset()`](http://php.net/reset) and [`end()`](http://php.net/end).  P.S. `0` will always be the 1st element, and for the last you can do `$arr[count($arr)-1]`.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

[`reset()`](https://www.php.net/reset) and [`end()`](https://www.php.net/end) does exactly this.

From the manual:

> [**`reset()`**](https://www.php.net/reset): Returns the value of the first array element, or FALSE if the array is empty.
>
> [**`end()`**](https://www.php.net/end): Returns the value of the last element or FALSE for empty array.

Example:

```
<?php
    $array = array(24.0,24.1,24.2,24.3,24.4,24.5,24.6);
    
    $first = reset($array);
    $last = end($array);
    
    var_dump($first, $last);
?>
```

Which outputs:

> float(24)
> float(24.6)

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/9G3QPc72)

---

**NOTE**: This will reset your array pointer meaning if you use [`current()`](https://www.php.net/reset) to get the current element or you've seeked into the middle of the array, [`reset()`](https://www.php.net/reset) and [`end()`](https://www.php.net/reset) will reset the array pointer (to the beginning and to the end):

```
<?php

$array = array(30.0, 24.0, 24.1, 24.2, 24.3, 24.4, 24.5, 24.6, 12.0);
    
// reset — Set the internal pointer of an array to its first element
$first = reset($array);

var_dump($first); // float(30)
var_dump(current($array)); // float(30)

// end — Set the internal pointer of an array to its last element
$last = end($array);
    
var_dump($last); // float(12)
var_dump(current($array)); // float(12) - this is no longer 30 - now it's 12
```

Comment: yeah but take a look at my array, when i use your code, i get:  "Warning: reset() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given" and the same for end()

Answer (score 12):

You can accessing array elements always with square bracket syntax. So to get the first use `0`, as arrays are zero-based indexed and `count($arr) - 1` to get the last item.

```
$firstEle = $arr[0];
$lastEle = $arr[count($arr) - 1];
```

Answer (score 6):

As of PHP 7.3, [array_key_first](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-first.php) and [array_key_last](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-last.php) is available

```
$first = $array[array_key_first($array)];    
$last = $array[array_key_last($array)];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`reset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) to get the first:

```
$firstEle = reset($arr);
```

> `reset()` rewinds array's internal pointer to the first element and returns the value of the first array element.

And [`end()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) to get the last:

```
$lastEle = end($arr);
```

> `end()` advances array's internal pointer to the last element, and returns its value.

Answer (score 1):

For first element: `current($arrayname);`

For last element: `end($arrayname);`

> current(): The current() function returns the value of the current
>   element in an array. Every array has an internal pointer to its
>   "current" element, which is initialized to the first element inserted
>   into the array.
>
> end(): The end() function moves the internal pointer to, and outputs,
>   the last element in the array. Related methods: current() - returns
>   the value of the current element in an array

```
$array = array(24.0,24.1,24.2,24.3,24.4,24.5,24.6);

$first = current($array);
$last = end($array);

echo 'First Element: '.$first.' :: Last Element:'.$last;
```

**Output result:**

```
First Element: 24 :: Last Element:24.6
```

Comment: Be aware of using this method.
`$array = array(1, 2, 3); echo current($array) . " "; echo end($array) . " "; echo current($array) . " ";`
returns 1 3 3

Answer (score 0):

We can acheive the goal using array values and array key also

Example : Array Values

```
<?php
    $array = array(24.0,24.1,24.2,24.3,24.4,24.5,24.6);        
    $array_values = array_values($array);

    // get the first item in the array
    print array_shift($array_values); 

    // get the last item in the array
    print array_pop($array_values);       
?>
```

Example : Array Keys

```
 <?php
    $array = array(24.0,24.1,24.2,24.3,24.4,24.5,24.6);        
    $array_keys = array_keys($array);

    // get the first item in the array
    print $array[array_shift($array_keys)]; 

    // get the last item in the array
    print $array[array_pop($array_keys)];       
?>
```