# Getting first and final value from 2D associative array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array  like this in php

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [month] => April-2014
            [total_booking] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [month] => May-2014
            [total_booking] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [month] => June-2014
            [total_booking] => 25
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [month] => October-2013
            [total_booking] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [month] => July-2014
            [total_booking] => 4
        )

)
```

i want to get the first `month` value and `final` value from this array. 
i am using `foreach()`  for doing this .without using for each is there any good option?

Comment: possible duplicate of [get first and last element in array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20052769/get-first-and-last-element-in-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the last element of the array using it's key. In your example they are number, integers so you can just count the array and use the result -1 to get the latest key

```
echo $array[count($array)-1]['month'];
echo $array[count($array)-1]['total_booking'];
```

Answer (score 1):

**array_shift($array);**  returns the first value from array

**array_pop($array);**  returns the last value from array

Comment: And modifies the original array. That should be noted.

Comment: for that you could create a temporary array

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
$first = reset($array)['month'];
$last  = end($array)['total_booking'];
```