# Get First And Last Data From conditioned foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach

Hello here i am with freaky problem,i wants the first data and last data from for-each loop. for that i have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070244/how-to-determine-the-first-and-last-iteration-in-a-foreach-loop) answer. this would be really helpful but here my condition is really a little bit complex.
I have loop as following

```
<?php
    $count = 0;
    $length = count($myDataArray);
    foreach ($myDataArray as $value) {
        if($count >= 7)
        {
            //Some Data to Print
            //this is first data for me

            <tr >
                <td><?=$myfinaldate?></td>
                <td><?=$stockdata[1]?></td>
                <td><?=$stockdata[2]?></td>
                <td><?=$stockdata[3]?></td>
                <td <?php if($count == 8)echo "style='background-color:#47ff77;'"; ?>><?=$stockdata[4]?></td>
                <td><?=$stockdata[5]?></td>
                <td><?php echo $mydate; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php

        }
        $count++;
    }
```

Now How can i Get First And Last Data from loop ?

Comment: Do you need to do this loop or you just want the first and last element ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get first and last element in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20052769/get-first-and-last-element-in-array)

Comment: @MickaelB phili maur is right

Comment: Just for clarification: He does not really want to get the first and last element, but the 8th and last one instead. So this duplicate does not cover the problem completely.

Comment: $data[7] for the 8th element isn't working ?

Comment: _Just a small point_ Your example is a little odd seeing as you dont actually use anything from `$value` anywhere in the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you could use your `length` attribute.
As you have the total of your array, just check
`myDataArray[0]` and `myDataArray[$length-1]` ?

Answer (score 0):

To fetch first and last value of the array use the below function :

```
$array = $myDataArray;

$array_values = array_values($myDataArray);

// get the first value in the array
print $array_values[0]; // prints 'first item'

// get the last value in the array
print $array_values[count($array_values) - 1]; // prints 'last item'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_values` to remove the keys of an array and replace them with indices. If you do this, you can access the specified fields directly. Like this you can check for your requirements on the array without looping over it, as shown in the `if`-conditions below:

```
$length = count($myDataArray);
$dataArrayValues = array_values($myDataArray);
$wantedFields = [];
if ($length >= 8) {
    $wantedFields[] = $dataArrayValues[7];
    if ($length > 8) {
        $wantedFields[] = end($dataArrayValues);
    }
}
```

Due to the conditions you will not print the 8th field twice in case it is the last field as well.

```
foreach ($wantedFields as $value) {
    <tr>
    ... //Your previous code
    </tr>
}
```